# Header fade on scroll down show on scroll up pulsing

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code is making my header fade in and out repeatedly rather than hiding it on scroll down and showing it on scroll up. Any ideas why

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (currentScrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
        $(".header").fadeOut();
    } else {
        $(".header").fadeIn();
    }
    lastScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this? link reference: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_scrollspy_affix&stacked=h

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  body {
    position: relative; 
  }
  .affix {
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
  }
  .navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }

  .affix ~ .container-fluid {
   position: relative;
   top: 50px;
  }
  #section1 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
  #section2 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #section3 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
  #section41 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
  #section42 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
  </style>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#F44336;color:#fff;height:200px;">
  <h1>Scrollspy & Affix Example</h1>
  <h3>Fixed navbar on scroll</h3>
  <p>Scroll this page to see how the navbar behaves with data-spy="affix" and data-spy="scrollspy".</p>
  <p>The navbar is attached to the top of the page after you have scrolled a specified amount of pixels, and the links in the navbar are automatically updated based on scroll position.</p>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>    

<div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section41" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section42" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but thats no use. The JS I posted should work fine but for some reason when the header shows on scroll up it pulses, like it fades in and out then back in and out. It should just show normally

Comment: You try add time inside fadeout and fadein when you scroll up and scroll down

Answer (score 0):

I used the jquery you gave. Check if this meets your requirement.

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (currentScrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
        $(".header").fadeOut();
    } else {
        $(".header").fadeIn();
    }
    lastScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
The Header
</div>
<div class="container">
First Content
</div>
<div class="container">
Second Content
</div>
<div class="container">
Third Content
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Find this solution in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/richierich25/d4q9zra0/7/)